# Encryption using a few string manipulations and <stdio.h> only

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, char

I am trying to use only one library  and I encountered a few issues. This program should do the following :

- it should have an encryption function and another one for decryption.
- string must be 8 capped letters or digs (`A-Z 0-9`)
- the process should be like this :

  - A :
    moving the given string 2 characters backwards
    before : `abcdefg`
     
    after :  `cdefgab`
  - B:Reverse the result of A Function. 
     
    before : `cdefgab`
    after  : `bagfedc`
  - C: Swap pairs characters with unpaired characters.
    before : `ereaeedf`
    after  : `reaeeefd`
  - D: Going through an encryption table.
    two arrays `[Original]` and `[Encrypted]`
    take the string and divide it to chars each char run through the table and take his original position (A = 1 , B = 2 , C =3 and so on) and going to [Encrypted] array and take the character that is in the same position .

    ```
    array[Original] = {"A","B","C","D","D","F");
    array[Encrypted]= {"%","a","h","k","c","^");
    ```

    before : `FACD`
    after  : `^%hk`

My problem now is with `Enc_Table` which doesn't work as expected.
I have no idea why. I have tried a few things nothing sorted it out.

My Code Source :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define charsize 8

bool isStringEncrypted(char[]);
void Encryption();
char* Rotate_R(char str[]);
char* Reverse(char str[]);
char* Swap(char str[]);
char* Enc_Table(char str[]);
int getPos(const char *array, size_t size, char c);

void main() {

    int choose = 0;
    while (choose != 3){
        printf("Menu: \n\n  Please choose an option: \n\n 1 - Encrypt \n 2 - Decrypt [Not Implemented Yet] \n 3 - Exit \n\nYour selection ? :");
        scanf("%d", &choose);
        switch (choose)                                
        {

            case 1:
                Encryption();
                break;

            case  2:
                //Decryption();
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            default:
                printf("Wrong choice, try again!\n");

        }

    }
}


void Encryption(){

    char str[charsize];
    char result[charsize];
    do {
        printf("please enter the string with 8 characters\n =>");
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("\n Variable Str Value  = %s \n", str);
    } while (isStringEncrypted(str) == false);


    printf("Swap = %s \n", Swap(str));
    printf("Rotate_R =  %s \n", Rotate_R(str));
    printf("Reverse = %s \n", Reverse(str));
    printf("Enc_Table = %s \n", Enc_Table(str));
    printf("\nEncrypted String : %s \n", Enc_Table(Reverse(Rotate_R(Swap(str)))));
    scanf("%s", result);
}


bool isStringEncrypted(char str[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int Letters = 0;
    int Numbers = 0;


    unsigned int len = 0;
    while (*(str + len)) len++;

    if (len != charsize)
    {
        printf(" \n %d = len != %d = Size \n", len, charsize);
        return false;
    }


    while (str[i] != NULL && i < charsize) {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z' || str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {

            if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
                Letters++;
            if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
                Numbers++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (i == charsize && (Letters >= 2) && (Numbers >= 2))
        return true;
    else return true;
}

char* Rotate_R(char str[])
{
    char x, y;
    int i;
    x = str[7];
    y = str[6];

    for (i = 5; i>-1; i--)
    {
        str[i + 2] = str[i];
    }
    str[0] = y;
    str[1] = x;

    return str;
}

char* Swap(char str[])
{
    int i;
    char Temp;

    for (i = 0; i < charsize; i += 2)
    {
        Temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[i + 1];
        str[i + 1] = Temp;
    }

    return str;
}

char* Reverse(char str[])
{
    unsigned int lens = 0;
    while (*(str + lens)) lens++;
    char temp;
    size_t len = lens - 1;
    size_t i;
    size_t k = len;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp = str[k];
        str[k] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;
        k--;
        if (k == (len / 2))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

char* Enc_Table(char str[])
{

    int i;
    unsigned int lens = 0;
    while (*(str + lens)) lens++;

    char dec[38] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '\0' };
    char enc[38] = { 'S', '5', 'P', 'W', 'A', 'R', '8', 'Q', 'I', 'V', 'B', '0', 'D', 'Z', '3', 'C', '2', 'H', '4', '1', 'K', '7', 'G', 'Y', '6', 'O', 'J', 'E', 'U', 'N', 'F', '9', 'M', 'L', 'T', 'X', '\0' };

    for (i = 0; i < charsize; i++)
    {
        int index = getPos(dec, sizeof(dec), str[i]);
        str[i] = enc[index];
        i++;
    }

    return str;
}

int getPos(const char *array, size_t size, char c)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == c)
            return (int)i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: One major problem is that you ask the user to enter eight characters, but then `scanf` will write ***nine*** characters to the destination array. This is because it also writes the string terminator character. Writing out of bounds of allocated memory of course leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), making your whole program ill-formed.

Comment: I have tried change it to 9 also and then where i check for size i will just do size - 1.. , yet still dont work.. somehow the array will remain unordered and problematic... and i still get exceptions..

Comment: anyone can help me , code updated  - the problem now is with the Enc_Table function.

Comment: you seem to swap twice, one time in your debug output, then when you call to encrypt it. also use fgets instead of scanf to have more control of  keyboard input, if a user writes a string longer than 8 then your program will most likely crash. your buffer needs to be at least 9 chars long at any rate to hold the \0 (fgets adds \n as well)

Answer (score 2):

Encryption table should work like this:

```
void table(char *str, int forward)
{
    const char dec[36] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    const char enc[36] = "S5PWAR8QIVB0DZ3C2H41K7GY6OJEUNF9MLTX";

    const char *from = forward ? dec : enc;
    const char *to   = forward ? enc : dec;

    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(str); i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 36; n++)
        {
            if (str[i] == from[n])
            {
                str[i] = to[n];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    strcpy(s, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

    table(s, 1);// encryption
    printf("%s\n", s);
    table(s, 0);// decryption
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Also the same function with strcspn:

```
void table(char *str, int forward)
{
    const char *dec = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    const char *enc = "S5PWAR8QIVB0DZ3C2H41K7GY6OJEUNF9MLTX";

    const char *from = forward ? dec : enc;
    const char *to   = forward ? enc : dec;

    char buf[2] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(str); i < len; i++)
    {
        buf[0] = str[i];
        int pos = strcspn(from, buf);
        if (pos < 36)
            str[i] = to[pos];
    }
}
```

While we are at it, a fast rotate function:

```
void rotate(char *str, int rotate, int direction /*1=rotate-right, 0=rotate-left*/)
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (!rotate || rotate >= length)
        return;

    int offset = direction ? (length - rotate) : rotate;

    char *left  = _strdup(str);
    char *right = _strdup(str + offset);

    //swap left and right to finish rotate 
    strcpy(str, right);
    strncat(str, left, offset);

    free(left);
    free(right);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that you could use `strcspn()` instead of the inner loop to get the offset on the `from` array, and then apply that index to the `to` array.  But otherwise, you've done a good job disentangling the work from question.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I made an update with `strcspn`. But I couldn't use pointers, I was forced to make an extra buffer. Maybe that's for another question.